# Default image size in IE8

Tags: javascript, image

I'm loading an image in IE8 as follows:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'images/starnohighlight.png';
```

The image is 30x30px @150dpi.

When I add the image to the page:

```
td.appendChild(img);
```

the image is displayed at a much enlarged size of 324x308. I know I could simply force it to be 30x30, because I know the dimensions of the source image, but I'd much prefer to just provide a 30x30 image on disk and display it in it's native size. If I need to change the resolution of the image (to say 72dpi) that'd be fine, too, or I could at least account for that in the code.

I haven't tested on other browsers, simply because I don't have access to any currently.

So, the question, in sum: **how can I display an image loaded as above at the native size?**

**Edits**:

I've also tried this with the same result:

```
var imgObj = new Image();
imgObj.src = 'images/starnohighlight.png';
```

I've removed all styles from the document. Still the same problem.

Comment: I think you might have some CSS applied to the `img` tag that makes it render that way. It shouldn't do that by default. Look in IE Dev Tools (F12) for the computed styles on the `img` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See my edit. Also, I removed all CSS links. I still have the same problem. Unfortunately I can't access dev tools (argh!).

Comment: Pretty strange. Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2JwXF/ You can see it is very simple and the img is displayed in it's original size. Now I would have to ask: are you **100%** positive the image you're supplying is 30px x 30px? Mind sharing a link to the image?

Comment: Mmm it works fine if I modify the jsfiddle for my image. It's a local image so I can't link to it. There must be something odd going on with my page. More hunting to do. Thanks very much for your help. If you make an answer something along the lines of your comment I'll give you a nice green tick :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you display an image like that, with no other settings affecting it, it *will* be displayed in the native size.

The resolution (PPI or DPI) setting in the image is ignored by the browser, so changing that will have no effect.

If the image is not showing up in the native size, you have some other setting affecting the image tag. You can use the developer tools (F12) in IE to examine what styles are actually affecting the element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See my edit. Also, I removed all CSS links. I still have the same problem. Unfortunately I can't access dev tools (argh!).